# Blockchain Android application

Tags: solidity, web3j

I want to create blockchain based android application. So someone please help me with which language I should code for smart contracts and all. Also tell me that can I run blockchain application in android studio and if yes then how can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which language I should code for smart contracts

This fully depends on the blockchain you want your app to work on. For ethereum and ethereum-compatible chains (polygon, avax-c, BSC etc.) your best choice is probably solidity but you have other options as well (Vyper, which is more python-like, or lower level languages like Huff).

> and all

Not sure what you mean here? If you're talking about the app in itself, i never made an android app so couldnt tell, but a quick google search suggests that the most popular languages for  Android app development are Java and Kotlin. Both have good web3-enabling libraries (here for [Java](https://github.com/web3j/web3j), and for [Kotlin](https://github.com/komputing/KEthereum) (of course, you  can use web3j as well in Kotlin). And of course you can use Android studio for that, as any other IDE.